# Constrained Delaunay with Info

Tags: cgal

I have this setup:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel       K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<FIntPoint, K> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<K>            Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb>              Tds;
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_tag                                Itag;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, Tds, Itag>  Delaunay;
typedef Delaunay::Point                                           Point;
typedef Delaunay::Vertex_handle                                   VertexHandle;
```

FIntPoint is a struct with 2 integers.

My vertices belong to border triangles of 2 separate terrain-like 3D meshes. I triangulate these vertices in 2D to connect these meshes. The info I need for each vertex is *(1)* which mesh it belongs to and *(2)* its vertex index within that mesh, so that I know where this vertex came from after triangulation, as more information is tied to these indices.

In this illustration, you can see the 2 meshes and their border triangles. I want to stitch these together:

[image: Illustration of the border triangles of the 2 meshes]

This is basically how I insert points, simplified:

```
Delaunay Triangulation;

for (...)
{
    // Insert a triangle from one of my meshes
    VertexHandle vh1 = Triangulation.insert(Point(a.Y, a.Z));
    vh1->info() = FIntPoint(iA, iM);
    VertexHandle vh2 = Triangulation.insert(Point(b.Y, b.Z));
    vh2->info() = FIntPoint(iB, iM);
    VertexHandle vh3 = Triangulation.insert(Point(c.Y, c.Z));
    vh3->info() = FIntPoint(iC, iM);

    // Add constraints to keep this triangle exactly how it was in the origin mesh
    Triangulation.insert_constraint(vh1, vh2);
    Triangulation.insert_constraint(vh2, vh3);
    Triangulation.insert_constraint(vh3, vh1);
}
```

My problem now is that when I try to retrieve the info, it is missing/incorrect. I get values outside of the range I'm inserting them.
This happens only with the constraints. When I comment out the lines with `insert_constraint`, it works as expected.

```
for (auto itFace = Triangulation.finite_faces_begin(); itFace != Triangulation.finite_faces_end(); itFace++)
{
    // Retrieve vertex info
    auto& a = itFace->vertex(0)->info();
    auto& b = itFace->vertex(1)->info();
    auto& c = itFace->vertex(2)->info();

    // ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong with the constraints?

Additionally, I want to limit the length of edges. I haven't attempted so add this limitation in my code yet, because I wanted to fix the described problem first. If you could provide an answer that includes a maximum edge length, that would be very helpful too.

Any help is appreciated. I've been sitting on this problem for a long time.

Comment: "missing/incorrect" means not initialized? This could be the case if you have constraints intersecting (thus creating new vertices). But you are using Exact_predicates_tag so you would get a runtime error. For the second question look at [this package](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html).

Comment: Yes, they seem not initialized, or somehow overridden. At least info `a` has values outside of the possible range (e.g. negative). However, `b` and `c` have values that look correct. Is there maybe something wrong with my definitions? Or could it be that inserting vertices of adjacent triangles twice causes a problem?

Comment: If you did init them they should not be unint then. Note that if you insert twice the same vertex, you'll modify an existing info.

Comment: The vertices that are inserted twice are identical, with the same info, so that should be fine then. Could there be anything wrong with my input positions/constraints? You said I would get a runtime error if constraints are intersecting, but there might be a chance that this is the case. I'll have to check that.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: My setup cannot guarantee that triangles don't overlap when projected to 2D, as the two terrain-like meshes can be angled, so I ended up using a different approach which does not involve constraints. Instead, I just discard any triangles that are too large, which takes care of most (but not all) visually unappealing cases. It's not an ideal solution, but right now I can't think of anything better that does not involve segmentation.